# Laravel 5.3 has the testing method onPage been removed?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm following through a video series on Laracasts to help me understand how to run tests in Laravel.

The test described is:

```
$this->visit('/')
     ->type('some query', '#term')
     ->press('Search')
     ->see('Search results for "some query"')
     ->onPage('search-results');
```

However Laravel complains that `onPage` is not a valid method.  I've looked through the docs but can't seem to find a change which best describes what alternative method to use.

I tried to do:

```
$this->visit('/')
     ->type('some query', '#term')
     ->press('Search')
     ->visit('/search-results')
     ->see('Search results for "some query"');
```

But it seems that the behaviour of that is to redirect to `/search-results` before the form submits, meaning the output message is not the same and the assertion fails.

Comment: Just to confirm, 5.4 or 5.3?

Comment: @AndyHolmes sorry, 5.3, my bad :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `seePageIs` method.

[Source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php#L176)

> Assert that the current page matches a given URI.

You can see more tips at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/application-testing).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the method was removed. I think you can use $this->seePageIs() instead
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php#L176